# How to fix the font that cut from the bottom in UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a custom font in the app and I have applied it on the Signup button and it has following result:
[image]

As you can see the 'g' has been cut from the bottom. The view is a UIButton with image on it and following properties:

- Custom font of size 22.7
- View Semantic: Force Right-to-Left
- Content Insets: Left:44.3, Right:24.7, Top:22 and Bottom:22
- Image Insets: Left only:11.7

I have tried to fix it by providing baselineOffset to value 1 in following code:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIButton {

     @IBInspectable var baselineOffset: CGFloat {
        set {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: newValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, title.count))
            self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
        }
        get { 0 }
    }

    var title: String {
        get { self.title(for: .normal) ?? "" }
    }
}
```

It fix the bottom cut but now the title cuts from the top.

Is there any way to add extra space for a title text to draw on the screen?